# Cannot convert from 'T[N][2]' to 'T[][2]'

Tags: c++

I have an API taking some options:

```
void init_api(const char* options[][2]);
```

I am allowed to pass a NULL pointer for no options, alternatively, an options array such as this can be passed:

```
const char* some_options[][2] = { {"opt1", "val1"}, 
                                  {"opt2", "val2"}, 
                                  {0,0} 
                                };
```

*This* works without problems:

```
...
init_api(some_options);
... or ...
init_api(NULL);
...
```

However, *this fails to compile*:

```
const char* my_options[][2] = NULL; // error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'const char *[][2]'
if(...) {
  my_options = some_options; // error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'const char *[4][2]' to 'const char *[][2]'
}
init_api(my_options); // no error here
```

What is going on here? Can someone explain this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To declare an empty array of array of pointers to const char, you should use:

```
const char* my_options[][2] = {};
```

You need to declare a pointer to an array of pointers to const char instead. I recommend using a typedef to simplify the syntax.

```
typedef const char* array_of_two_cstring[2];
array_of_two_cstring* my_options = NULL;
if (...) {
    my_options = some_options;
}
init_api(my_options);
```

In C++ (it is herited from C), array can be implicitly converted to pointer (only once though, that is `char[]` is compatible with `char*` but `char[][]` is compatible with `char*[]` but not `char**). However, the variable cannot be reassigned. So here you need to use a pointer instead of an array.

The `init_api` option accepts `NULL` as a parameter because for the compiler, its prototype is `void init_api(char const* (*)[2])` (the first array degenerated into a pointer), and `NULL` is a valid pointer.

Comment: Yes, but then how comes the function defined with this same definition accepts NULL values? This is the user's question I guess.

Comment: Updated my answer to explains what the OP issue is and what is the correct syntax to use.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler must know the array size.

If you omit the size of the array (ie: using `[]`) you need to initialize the array with the definition, in order to let the compiler count how many items that array will contain.

Moreover you are assigning a pointer (`NULL`) to an array: `const char *x[][2]` is an array of two pointers to `const char`.

---

**Edit**:

In C++ (as in C), arrays can decay into pointers when you use them (with three exceptions which are not interesting here).

When you pass an array to a function expecting an array, what happens is that you actually pass a pointer to the array, since the array decays; you cannot pass an array by value in C or C++.

For this reason you can pass `NULL` to your function; the function parameter will be `NULL`, and if you try to access the array within your function (`options[0]`) your application will crash: you'll be dereferencing an invalid pointer.

You cannot however set your array variable to `NULL`, since it's not a pointer, it's an array: it will only decay when you'll use it in an expression.

Comment: That still doesn't answer the user's question I believe. What you all said is true, but no body explained why the compiler (apparently MSVC) accept `NULL` to be passed for `init_api` while it basically has the same definition as the other one which the compiler is not accepting `NULL` for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
const char* options[][2]
```

is an array of const char* pointers. You can't assign a pointer to an array.

Comment: Why? It's just a pointer underneath. And it can be NULL when used as a function parameter.

Comment: @Martin - False. Arrays decay to pointers, but a pointer to an array is by definition never `NULL`.

Comment: @Chris: what exactly is false about the *fact* that I *can* pass NULL to a function taking an argument of T[][2] ??

Comment: @Martin - Nothing. What's false is that an array is a pointer underneath. In `func(int arr[N])`, `arr` is a pointer, but in `func() { int arr[N]; }`, `arr` is not. You can't assign anything to an array, nor can you initialize one to `NULL`. You can initialize the _elements_ to `NULL` if that's what you want to do, but not the array itself in your main function.

Comment: @Chris: See. That nearly would have been a good *answer* by itself. :-)

Comment: @Martin - I seem to have made a bad habit of writing answers in the comments sections during the past week or so. I need to get that out of my system.

Answer (score 1):

A parameter declared as being an array of type `T[N]` or `T[]` becomes actually a parameter of type `T*`. Same is done for functions (a parameter declared as `R(Params)` becomes actually a parameter of type `R(*)(Params...)`).

Such transformation however is not done for other declarations. The reason it's done for function by-value parameters is that there is no way in C to actually copy an array directly (that is, to actually copy its contents) and it doesn't make sense to try and copy a function either, so such parameters are transformed in a way that conveys their purpose in a meaningful way.

So while you are initializing a pointer in the function parameter case, you are trying to initialize an array in the other case.